# Is it feasible to run a Support Vector Machine Kernel on a device with <= 1 MB RAM and <= 10 MB ROM?

Tags: python, c, performance, memory-management, svm

Some preliminary testing shows that a project I'm working on could potentially benefit from the use of a Support-Vector-Machine to solve a tricky problem. The concern that I have is that there will be major memory constraints. Prototyping and testing is being done in python with scikit-learn. The final version will be custom written in C. The model would be pre-trained and only the decision function would be stored on the final product. There would be <= 10 training features, and <= 5000 training data-points. I've been reading mixed things regarding SVM memory, and I know the default sklearn memory cache is 200 MB. (Much larger than what I have available) Is this feasible? I know there are multiple different types of SVM kernel and that the kernel's can also be custom written. What kernel types could this potentially work with, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're that strapped for space, you'll probably want to skip `scikit` and simply implement the math yourself.  That way, you can cycle through the data in structures of your own choosing.  Memory requirements depend on the class of SVM you're using; a two-class linear SVM can be done with a single pass through the data, considering only one observation at a time as you accumulate sum-of-products, so your command logic would take far more space than the data requirements.

If you need to keep the entire data set in memory for multiple passes, that's "only" 5000*10*8 bytes for floats, or 400k of your 1Mb, which *might* be enough room to do your manipulations.  Also consider a slow training process, re-reading the data on each pass, as this reduces the 400k to a triviality at the cost of wall-clock time.

All of this is under your control if you look up a usable SVM implementation and alter the I/O portions as needed.

Does that help?